# polymorphic code always has same result

Tags: java, c#

Lets consider I have Class B and C which is inherited from class B:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
 class B
 {
    public void foo(B obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B1 ");
    }

    public void foo(C obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B1 ");
    }
 }

 class C : B
 {
    public void foo(B obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C1 ");
    }

    public void foo(C obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C1 ");
    }
 }
 public class Program
 {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B c = new C();
        B b = new B();

        b.foo(c);
        c.foo(b);
        c.foo(c);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
}
```

I am getting these results:

```
B1

B1

B1
```

I don't understand what happened exactly specially for the part:

```
c.foo(b); // prints B1

c.foo(c); // prints B1
```

Note: this question is just a mirror of the java version which prints:

```
B1

C1

C1
```

It will be great if someone can explain why C# print different values than Java for exactly same OOP code!

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler warnings should tell you enough. It tells you your `C.foo` hides the method `B.foo` since you are not using inheritance. Instead of you are just overwriting a previous method declaration.

You should use `virtual` and `override` in C# to declare method inheritance.

```
class B
{
    public virtual void foo(B obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B1 ");
    }

    public virtual void foo(C obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B1 ");
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public override void foo(B obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C1 ");
    }

    public override void foo(C obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C1 ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at your debug console, you will see:

```
warning CS0108: 'C.foo(B)' hides inherited member 'B.foo(B)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
warning CS0108: 'C.foo(C)' hides inherited member 'B.foo(C)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```

If you want to know more, read [Inheritance and Derived Classes (C# vs Java)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&.MSPPError=-2147217396)